# Dynamic repeater controls getting lost after post back

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created dynamic radio button/check box controls with help of a repeater. But the controls are getting lost after postback.
as an example, if i check the radion button which is i create using the repeater all the radio buttons will disappear

here is my aspx code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server" OnItemCommand="myRepeater_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="myRepeater_ItemDataBound">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr class="">
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Address
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Age
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Year
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlSelect" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"></asp:Panel>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%#Eval("Name")%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%#Eval("Address")%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%#Eval("Age")%>&nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%# Eval("Year")%>&nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

my .cs code

```
myRepeater.DataSource = *DataSource*;

    myRepeater.DataBind();

    protected void myRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            if (** condition 01 **)
            {
                if (** condition 02 **)
                {
                    RadioButton rdoBtn = new RadioButton();
                    rdoBtn.ID = "rbtnID";
                    rdoBtn.EnableViewState = true;
                    rdoBtn.GroupName = "GroupName";
                    rdoBtn.AutoPostBack = true;
                    rdoBtn.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.rdoBtnChecked_Changed);
                    string script = "SetUniqueRadioButton('myRepeater.*GroupName',this)";
                    rdoBtn.Attributes.Add("onclick", script);
                    Panel pnlRbtnSet = e.Item.FindControl("pnlSelect") as Panel;
                    pnlRbtnSet.Controls.Add(rdoBtn);
                }
                else 
                {
                    CheckBox chkBox = new CheckBox();
                    chkBox.ID = "chkBxID";
                    chkBox.Checked = true;
                    chkBox.EnableViewState = true;
                    Panel pnlChkBoxesSet = e.Item.FindControl("pnlSelect") as Panel;
                    pnlChkBoxesSet.Controls.Add(chkBox);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void rdoBtnChecked_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

i have set enableViewState=true for both the drawing panel and each control which is creating dynamically. but it does not work. please help me...

Comment: this link may help you  this link may help you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/502251/How-to-create-controls-dynamically-in-ASP-NET-and

Comment: @SruthiSuresh: i tried it. but did not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to create dynamic controls you have to recreate them on every postback. So `ItemDataBound` is inappropriate since it's only triggered when the repeater is getting databound. Use `ItemCreated` instead.

```
protected void myRepeater_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        if (** condition 01 **)
        {
            if (** condition 02 **)
            {
                RadioButton rdoBtn = new RadioButton();
                rdoBtn.ID = "rbtnID";
                rdoBtn.EnableViewState = true;
                rdoBtn.GroupName = "GroupName";
                rdoBtn.AutoPostBack = true;
                rdoBtn.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.rdoBtnChecked_Changed);
                string script = "SetUniqueRadioButton('myRepeater.*GroupName',this)";
                rdoBtn.Attributes.Add("onclick", script);
                Panel pnlRbtnSet = e.Item.FindControl("pnlSelect") as Panel;
                pnlRbtnSet.Controls.Add(rdoBtn);
            }
            else 
            {
                CheckBox chkBox = new CheckBox();
                chkBox.ID = "chkBxID";
                chkBox.Checked = true;
                chkBox.EnableViewState = true;
                Panel pnlChkBoxesSet = e.Item.FindControl("pnlSelect") as Panel;
                pnlChkBoxesSet.Controls.Add(chkBox);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean not using ItemDataBound ..? for the repeater i have another data list to bind. along with that data i have to insert this checkbox or radio button. can we use both ItemDataBound  and ItemCreated ..? can we use ItemCreated only to create dynamic controls ?

Comment: thanks for the help. it worked with both of ItemDataBound and ItemCreated

Comment: i set a value for the controls, after a post back value is not there. i set the value using **DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "UserID").ToString()**. but after post back DataItem is null. its obvious since ItemDataBound not triggered after a post back. any solution for this...?